# UserProfile in MVC5/EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

In `SimpleMembership` there used to be `UserProfile`, but not in Identity 1 & 2. What is the correct substitute in Identity?

AppliationUser?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to store profile information now. Basically, just inherit from IdentityUser and add your custom data. Here is a good article that compares identity with simple membership: http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html

Comment: So instead of using `UserProfile`, I can use `ApplicationUser` and get the `Roles` for that `ApplicationUser` and such?

Comment: Well, you can simply annotate your controller actions (    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]) or you could use the Identity UserManager to check roles.  HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().IsInRole(UserId, "Admin");